How can I move my trained model to another python notebook?
I have a python notebook that contains several functions such as pre_process,.. and it contains my model which I trained. Now I'm supposed to submit a python notebook that contains my trained model for further testing. How can I do that?
I know that when running a cell it saves the variables for all cells to use, can I maybe link the two files and call the model from there?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You usually want to save a machine learning model as a Pickle (. pkl) file.
# Saving the model
import pickle
with open('model.pkl', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(model, file)

This can then be loaded again later.
with open('model.pkl', 'rb') as file:
    loaded_model = pickle.load(file)

There are other methods depending on how you trained your model.
